# NestJS app build with docker can't access postgres database in the same docker network: ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, nestjs

I want to run my app on my local machine within Docker. I don't want to optimize the size of my docker app or build it for production now.

Docker builds my backend-api app and postgres-db successfully. But I can only access the docker postgres database outside my docker e.g. with dbeaver installed on my computer. Also if I start my backend-api app WITHOUT Docker with "npm run start", my app can also access the database without any errors and can also write into the posgres db. Only when I build the backend-api with Docker and launch the app inside the Docker, I get this error. Since this only happens within Docker, I assume that something important is missing in my Dockerfile.

My **docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3'

services:

  backend:
    build: .
    container_name: backend-api
    command: npm run start
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/backend
    networks:
      - docker-network
    depends_on:
      - database

  database:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: backend-db
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - postgresdb/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    networks:
      - docker-network
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: devuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: devpw
      POSTGRES_DB: devdb

volumes:
  postgresdb:

networks:
  docker-network:
    driver: bridge
```

My **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:16.15.0-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/backend

COPY . .

RUN npm install
```

**sudo docker-compose up --build** output:

```
Starting backend-db ... done
Recreating backend-api ... done
Attaching to backend-db, backend-api
backend-db  | 
backend-db  | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
backend-db  | 
backend-db  | 2022-05-03 20:35:46.065 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.2 (Debian 14.2-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
backend-db  | 2022-05-03 20:35:46.066 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
backend-db  | 2022-05-03 20:35:46.066 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
backend-db  | 2022-05-03 20:35:46.067 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
backend-db  | 2022-05-03 20:35:46.071 UTC [26] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-05-03 20:35:02 UTC
backend-db  | 2022-05-03 20:35:46.077 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
backend-api | 
backend-api | > backend@0.0.1 start
backend-api | > nodemon
backend-api | 
backend-api | [nodemon] 2.0.15
backend-api | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
backend-api | [nodemon] watching path(s): src/**/*
backend-api | [nodemon] watching extensions: ts
backend-api | [nodemon] starting `IS_TS_NODE=true ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts`
backend-api | [Nest] 30  - 05/03/2022, 8:35:50 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
backend-api | [Nest] 30  - 05/03/2022, 8:35:50 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +73ms
backend-api | [Nest] 30  - 05/03/2022, 8:35:50 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +1ms
backend-api | [Nest] 30  - 05/03/2022, 8:35:50 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +0ms
backend-api | [Nest] 30  - 05/03/2022, 8:35:50 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +1ms
backend-api | [Nest] 30  - 05/03/2022, 8:35:50 PM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
backend-api | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
backend-api |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16)
backend-api | [Nest] 30  - 05/03/2022, 8:35:53 PM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (2)...
```

My **ormconfig.ts**:

```
import { ConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm';

const config: ConnectionOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  username: 'devuser',
  password: 'devpw',
  database: 'devdb',
  entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  synchronize: false,
  migrations: [__dirname + '/**/migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}'],
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: 'src/migrations',
  },
};

export default config;
```

Please let me know what other information you would like me to provide. I'm new to the Docker world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run a docker container `localhost` results in the `container's` localhost, not your machine's, so it's not the right host to use. As you're using `docker-compose`, a docker network is automatically created using the service's names as `host`s. So instead of using `localhost` for you database host, you can use `database` as the host, and now the docker network will route the request properly to the `database` service as defined in your `docker-compose.yml` file

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same issue and this docker-compose.yml setup worked for me

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  database:
    container_name: db
    image: postgres:14.2
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD
  backend:
    container_name: api
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - database
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=database
      - DATABASE_PORT=5432
      - DATABASE_USER=postgres
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD
      - DATABASE_NAME
      - DATABASE_SYNCHRONIZE
      - NODE_ENV
```

Following were two main notable changes

1. changed the host to `database` so the docker network will route the
   request properly to the database service as defined in your
   docker-compose.yml file.
2. added a user `postgres` as default
   PostgreSQL user